# Why the ".deps.json" file on release folder and publish output folder size are difference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, msbuild, .net-core

I build on project and checked on release folder size is **"280KB"**
but when I try on publish output file size is **"296KB"**

**Tested on .net core 2.0 and VS 2017**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The output in bin/[Configuration] is only meant to be used for local development. Together with the runtimeconfig.dev.json this file specifies the dependency closure of your build output and references are resolved from your local NuGet package cache. If you copy the build output to another machine/user, it will not work.

For deployment, all needed DLLs are copied to the build output and a deps.json file is generated using a slightly different input to describe the dependency closure of the published application.

This publish output is generated by either Visual Studio publish output or by using

```
dotnet publish -c Release
```

in the console.

Comment: Thanks you so much, it's worked good on console, but how I can use this script on CCNET ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926331/how-can-build-dotnet-publish-on-cruisecontrol-server

Comment: Martin is this method only suitable for deploying full apps? In case of a library which is the recommended method to generate the build? (I mean for using DLLs in other .NET applications).

Comment: I suggest to reference projects or NuGet packages. I don't recommend referencing dll files directly - it can get you in trouble with dependency resolution (and binding redirects on full framework applications). But either way, always use `dotnet publish` for now. There is some discussion going on about how dlls could also be shared for dynamic plugin systems (which currently don't really work well) - https://github.com/dotnet/designs/pull/47

Comment: As I see in my case it is better to go for the "reference project" option because it is a huge library and 'dotnet publish' generates more than 20 files and some folders and I think it is a mess for reference and version updating. Thanks for the suggestion