# Leaking of windows account name into .Net Core App configuration

Tags: windows, .net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am experimenting with building *MyApp*, a c# based command line utility using .Net Core.  In creating an msi installer for this utility I worked out by a process of elimination that the "*MyApp.runtimeconfig.dev*" file has to be included for a correct installation that will allow *MyApp* to run on another Windows machine.  (and that the same file is generated and required for both Debug and Release builds)

The default contents of this file are:

```
{
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "additionalProbingPaths": [
      "C:\\Users\\MyDevAccount\\.dotnet\\store\\|arch|\\|tfm|",
      "C:\\Users\\MyDevAccount\\.nuget\\packages",
      "C:\\Microsoft\\Xamarin\\NuGet",
      "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\NuGetFallbackFolder"
    ]
  }
}
```

What surprises me is the inclusion of the "*C:\Users\MyDevAccount\*" path, which is a direct indication of the account on the windows machine that I used to develop "*MyApp*".  I also suspect that the reference to Xamarin may be because I installed Xamarin development tools when I installed VS2019.

Neither of these aspects are likely to be valid on the system I will deploy MyApp to.  So my questions are:

1. Is the NuGetFallbackFolder the only Probing Path that is relevant?
2. How do I get VS2019 to not include the irrelevant paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of reading online I discovered an [interesting answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49919079/31326) that explains what I am seeing.  And my confusion relates to what is effectively a change to what is a "Release" build in Visual Studio between a .Net Core and a non .Net Core project.

From that answer:

> The output in bin/[Configuration] is only meant to be used for local
>   development. Together with the runtimeconfig.dev.json this file
>   specifies the dependency closure of your build output and references
>   are resolved from your local NuGet package cache. If you copy the
>   build output to another machine/user, it will not work.

While I did find that the copying all of the Release folder to another computer did work, this answer hints at why the "*MyApp.runtimeconfig.dev*" file turns up in the that folder in the first place - Release is no longer Release!

The correct way to "Release" a .Net Core App is instead to "Publish" it.

When I published my .Net Core App, the resultant output no longer contained the "*MyApp.runtimeconfig.dev*" file, thus basically making this question moot.